# How to apply autoformatting in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Neither shortcuts e.g. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> nor options provided by the taskbar:

[image]

seem to be able to apply autoformatting in [Google Apps Script](https://script.google.com).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There's is a shortcut to auto indent in GAS.

The short-cut is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.
Make sure you have all your code selected.

As a best practice try to always use
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all immediately before <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>

This will change spacing in the whole document if all your code is selected.

Answer (score 7):

The only auto-formatting feature provided by Script Editor is to indent code **as you type it**. This is done when the indent button is enabled, as it is on your screenshot.

[image: button to indent]

For example, after typing `function test() {` and pressing Enter you find that the cursor's position is two spaces to the right of the margin. That's what that button does.

There is no built-in tool for re-indenting a code block that is already entered. Use a 3rd party tool such as http://jsbeautifier.org/ (in which the default indent is 4 spaces but can be changed to 2 to be consistent with the Script Editor).

Ctrl-Shift-F is an unrelated shortcut to toggle a more compact view of the editor's controls. There is no keyboard shortcut for Indent button that I know of.

Comment: If you script is not autoindenting properly this will correct it.  I did for me anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ES6+ features with the new Apps Script runtime powered by V8, the built-in formatter may get confused. In this case, using the [Prettier online formatter](https://prettier.io/playground/) may help. Simply copy-paste code between your Script Editor and Prettier formatter windows.